# How to get current date - two weeks date using Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I am working with `Postgresql` database. I need to get date which is two weeks prior to current date using `Postgresql` database.

```
select date(now() - interval '2 week') from test_base
```

If today's date is `2014-05-08` then above sql should give me `2014-04-24`?

But somehow above query is not working at all?

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/1582 ..its working

Comment: Are you sure you need the "from test_base" part in there? It is not used in your select statement. And if that table does not have any rows, your query will not return anything. Simply doing "select date(now() - interval '2 week')" should suffice, if you're doing this to test/learn.

Comment: Downvoted because "is not working at all" is really not a useful description of a problem, and you've been around Stack Overflow long enough to do better. **Always show the exact text of any error message**. A copy'n'paste of a `psql` session, or an SQLFiddle, is even better.

Answer (score 16):

```
SELECT now() - interval '2 week';
```

This works just fine. What is the exact error you are getting?

Since you are not pulling any data from table `test_base` there is no need to include that in a `FROM` clause.